# Find additional heating and cooling needed by having a specific wall

Tags: materials, civil-engineering, heat-transfer

I need some help to a design problem at my university. The design work is about designing a prefabricated wall panel. I calculated the U Value of the external wall and it is 0.0136 W/m<sup>2</sup>K. The thickness of the wall is 0.353 m and total area equal to 3 m x 6 m = 18 m2 (assumed no openings).

What I need to do now is to estimate how much energy do I need to maintain the inside temperature. I know that the maximum summer outside temperature is 30°C and the minimum in winter -20°C. How can I calculate the additional cooling and heating I need by having this wall?

It is basically a whole design project with the purpose of creating a prefabricated panel that can meet the needs of a specific country that was given. It was entirely flexible, nothing was given, just a city to make it fit there!  I divided my work as I thought it would be better and one part of it was the thermal properties.I tried to choose materials that can meet a rigorous U value of 0.13 and now I would like to show how much better it is in terms of operational energy (cooling and heating). After a research I did I found that probably I could calculate the heat loss and heat gain (the simplest I found with the data I have is by this Ht = A U (ti - to) and then according to my results propose a heating system or cooling etc. But I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.. this is why I asked some help.

Comment: What initial have you done to figure out this problem so far? Per this site's policy, our goal is to help you come up with the solution not to outright give you the solution.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a "[homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832)" (notice the quotation marks). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: So your end goal is to make a recommendation of what systems the building will need to maintain a certain temperature throughout all seasons? The formula you mentioned is the basic conductive heat transfer model, and it will allow you to determine the amount of heat you will need to add or remove per unit time. I would say this method would give you a reasonable "first order" approximation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, this is what thought to give an approximation. I don't have a specific location, just the city and I found that the maximum temp in summer can be 30°C and minimum in winter -20°C. I used these values to find a heat flow of my wall as the worst case scenario in summer and winter. Now, by having the heat gain and lost in W how can I choose a specific heating or cooling system?

Comment: Isn't the project goal for you to figure out what type of system you could use? There are many ways to heat and cool structures, and each method has pros and cons; it is up to the designer to optimize the cost of the system, energy usage, service lifetime, etc. and make recommendations. The basic engineering concept would be that your system(s) would have to complete the energy balance and either provide or remove the appropriate amount of heat.